# Main effect insignificant: should I estimate an interaction with it?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, interaction

As the title reveals, does it make sense to estimate an interaction when you already see that a main effect is insignificantly different from 0 in regression?

In my study I am actually interested in this interaction, as its part of my research question. Can I conclude the interaction will be insignificant too, or can it happen that the interaction will be significant? I usually only estimate interactions when the main effects are significant, hence I am asking/unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the only requirement for an interaction term (between two variables) in a regression model, is that both main effect variables must be present in the model.  The main effects do not have to be significant, but rather just be in the model.